# Show that $f_n (x)$ converges to $f(x)=0 \ \forall x$

Tags: pointwise-convergence, sequence-of-function

$f_n$ is defined on $[0,1] \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $,

$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} n(1-nx) &\mbox{if } \ 0 \leq x < \frac{1}{n} \\ 
0 & \mbox{if } \ \frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq 1 \end{cases}  $

The book says that show that $f_n$ converges to $f(x)=0 \ \forall x \in [0,1] $

But at $0, f_n(0)=n$ which does not converge. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There was a similar exam in a past paper of my university which asked to find the pointwise function but there was a point where the limit didn't exist.

Comment: You are right… $f_n(0) = n$ hence $f_n(0) \to \infty$. But $f_n$ converges to $0$ $\lambda$-a.s. if you consider $\lambda$ as  Lebesgue-Borel measure because single points are nullsets.

Comment: @Gono That topic is not covered by my course(neither have I studied it). So, how should I answer this question?

Comment: Then you are right and $f_n(0) \to \infty$ hence $f_n \not\to 0$.

Comment: @Adayah Yes, I did.

Comment: Thanks for the help, both of you.